# Need formula to vlookup comma separated values in a single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vlookup

I'm trying to do a vlookup on a cell with comma separated items in it for the lookup_value, referencing another file that has 1 item per cell. My example below has 6 items in the csv cell, and i want the lookup to return any matching values (summed).

[image: Vlookup Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you want SUMIFS inside a SUMPRODUCT:

First we need to parse the lookup values, we can do that with MID and ROW to create the array of lookups:

```
TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX($XFD:$XFD,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999))
```

This will create an array of the lookup values in A2: `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`

Then we pass the array to the SUMIFS():

```
SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX($XFD:$XFD,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999)))
```

Then we use SUMPRODUCT to iterate that array and sum the results of each:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX($XFD:$XFD,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this, worked perfect!

Comment: @EricFox please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: 1 more thing, if I have dates in column D, and I need to add a date range to the sumifs, where in the equation would that go? For example, I would need it to look for all prices that fall between 7/28/2019 & 8/31/201. I know typically I would just use =sumifs(D2,">="&date(2019,7,28),D2,"<="&date(2019,8,31).

Comment: you would add: `,D:D,">="&date(2019,7,28),D:D,"<="&date(2019,8,31)`before the last two `)`